# VBA Userform: Search for existing number and choose row

Tags: excel, vba

I got an excel sheet which has data about customers.
I created a userform, which lets me input all information and save it.

Now I want the userform to check column A (customer nº), and if the customer nº of the userform is already in there, I want it to select that row as active row/cell.
If not, I want the active cell to be the first empty cell in column A.

I've tried a lot so far (For, if & elseif, ...) but nothing seems to work.

Can anyone help me? Thanks a lot and a nice day

Edit: This is my latest try:

```
For i = 3 To 300000
wert = "A" & i
If Range(wert).Value = custno Then
ActiveCell = wert

ElseIf wert = "" Then
ActiveCell = Range(wert).Offset(1, 0)
End If
Next
```

Comment: If you post what you have tried so far, we can help to fix the issues in your code

Comment: you can't "set" the ActiveCell like that - you need `Range(wert).Activate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test the code below :

Edit (Even though it's not an optimized solution) :

```
Sub myTest()
        lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        found = 0
        i = 1
        Do While found = 0 And i <= lastRow
            If Cells(i, 1).Value = custno Then
                'Activate the cell
                Cells(i, 1).Activate
                found = 1
            End If
            i = i + 1
        Loop

        If found = 0 Then
            ' Get The first empty cell in column A
            On Error Resume Next
            firstEmptyCell = Range("A1:A" & Rows.Count).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Row
            If firstEmptyCell = vbNullString Then
                n = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            Else
                n = firstEmptyCell
            End If
            ' If not found Activate The Last empty cell in column A
            Cells(n, 1).Activate
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` gets columns A last not empty cell row index "from the bottom", i.e. there may be other empty cells in between this cell and first row, while OP wants _"the first empty cell in column A"_

Comment: should be fine too.

Comment: It doesn't work the way I intended, because I have a couple of other lines before and after, I can't use the "Exit Sub". Is there another way to skip the 2nd part with the empty cell as soon as the first is correct?

Answer (score 2):

use this

```
Dim f As Range
With Range("A1", Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)) ' reference all column A cells from row 1 down to last not empty one
    Set f = .Find(what:=Me.custno, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole) ' try finding 'custno'
    If f Is Nothing Then 'if unsuccessful
        .Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Offset(1).Activate ' activate the first not empty cell
    Else 'else
        f.Activate ' activate found cell
    End If
End With
```

Comment: @spqx, any feedback?

Comment: unfortunatly doesn't work. I don't get any errors but the changes in the userform won't get saved in the table.

Comment: Your question wasn’t about any change in userform to be saved in the sheet. It was about selecting cells in the sheet with relation to some userform control value

Comment: Yes you're right. The second part of the code is about writing userform input into the active column.
I've tested again, and your code doesn't select an empty or used cell, it keeps stuck at A1.

Comment: Step through it: place a breakpoint (press F9) at the line “With Range(“A1”,...” and once the execution stops there press F8 to step to subsequent codelines and query relevant variables in Immediate Window (CTRL-G to pop it out), e.g. type “?Me.custno” and press return and see its current value

Comment: You code just works fine. I had a line from an old try between the subs which changed the worksheet.
After deleting the trouble causing line it works as intended. Thanks a lot!